# Redirected pages are not working properly in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

all the pages are parsed through index pages but if the pages is parsed through the index page then PHP codes are not parsed. And in the page source code all the php code are showing. I have use the .htaccess file and the code is given below:

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [R,L]
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
<Files 403.shtml>
 order allow,deny
 allow from all
 </Files>
```

Getting all the file contents from the function in the index page. The function is:

```
public function getPageContent()
{
    $html = implode('', file($this->_ROOT.$this->getPage()));
    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: So you dont want to redirect php files ?

Comment: yah i want to redirect php files but the php coeds in the redirected files are not parsed. For example if the home.php page is redirected to the index.php page but the codes in the home.php page are not parsed.

Comment: What are you doing in your index.php? You `include("")` the home.php ?

Comment: I have edit my question and the function in which file contents that get in the index file is given in the question

Comment: Well, how should we say what happens with only some miraculous `file($this->_ROOT.$this->getPage()`? Where is the implementation of that object $this refers to?

Comment: arkascha;- If you want to get description for $this then i have to send all of my code to you.

Answer (score 1):

Whats happening is that you just request the content of the file.

`file()` get you everything what is inside of that file, it gives it back in plain text. You should need to include the requested page in your index.php, for example:

The request: `home.php -> index.php?p=home.php`

```
.htaccess
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [R,L]


index.php
<?php
  /* Do some checks to secure the input. */
  include($_GET['p']);
?>
```